# uploadify - go to another url when completed uploading process

Tags: uploadify

how to make uploadify to redirect on completion of the uploading task

I add this

```
'oncomplete' : function(){
    location.href="imthepage";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a `location.href="my_new_page.htm"` into the callback of your choice, e.g.  `onAllComplete`.

Comment: thanks, you mean

'oncomplete' : function(){
    location.href="imthepage";
}

but its not working I have given this in the head but after uploading nothing is happening (not redirecting)

Comment: @Rahul maybe show the code - you can edit it into your question.